# How to simplify expressions with complex exponents?

Tags: simplifying-expressions, complex

I have the following expression

```
expr = -E^(-I k) Sqrt[ E^(I k) k1 k2 + E^(3 I k) k1 k2 + E^(2 I k) (k1^2 + k2^2)]
```

with real k, k1, and k2. I want to simplify it to

```
-Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2 + 2 k1 k2 Cos[k]]
```

How do I get Mathematica to do this?

I've tried using some combinations of `Simplify`, `ComplexExpand`, and `ExpToTrig` without success.

Comment: Something to adjust: `N[-E^(-I k) Sqrt[
    E^(I k) k1 k2 + E^(3 I k) k1 k2 + E^(2 I k) (k1^2 + k2^2)] /. {k ->
     1, k1 -> 2, k2 -> -2, k3 -> 3}]` results in `-1.9177 + 0. I`, but `N[Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2 + 2 k1 k2 Cos[k]] /. {k -> 1, k1 -> 2, k2 -> -2, 
   k3 -> 3}]` performs  `1.9177`.

Comment: `expr // FullSimplify[#, 
   TransformationFunctions -> {Automatic, PowerExpand}] &`

Comment: @Syed, that works perfectly. If you wish to write that as an answer, I'll be happy to accept it.

Comment: If you have started learning Mathematica, then you will find that the introductory [book](https://www.wolfram.com/language/elementary-introduction/2nd-ed/) written by the inventor is a good learning resource. There is a [fast intro for math students](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-math-students/en/) as well as a [fast intro for programmers](https://www.wolfram.com/language/fast-introduction-for-programmers/en/) to choose from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternative way (how we would do it by "hand")

```
expr = -E^(-I k) Sqrt[E^(I k) k1 k2 + E^(3 I k) k1 k2 + E^(2 I k) (k1^2 + k2^2)]
expr/.Exp[x_]*Sqrt[y_] :> Sqrt[ FullSimplify[Exp[2x]*y] ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or using method by Syed

```
FullSimplify[expr,TransformationFunctions->{Automatic,PowerExpand}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
expr /. -E^(-I k)*Sqrt[a_] -> -Sqrt[a*E^(-2 I k)] // 
  ExpToTrig // Simplify

(* -Sqrt[k1^2 + k2^2 + 2 k1 k2 Cos[k]]  *)
```

Have fun!